# Duplicate instances on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I duplicate my instance in sql server !?

I want to have a test instance on my same server just for testing purposes instead of applying all tests on the real data.

is it possible to create an new instance and copy all the same data and users with permissions on a new instance?

Or is there any other way other than VM, because my DB is in running and in use from other user but I want to do my test environment without disturbing other users. And all that on the same server.

Comment: yes it is possible to create a test instance on same server

Comment: Just reinstall the sql server from installer and at some step, when asked for instance, provide new instance name. Data and users can be copied.

Comment: Hope this info from Microsoft helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server

Comment: Backup your database > create new DBName > restore

Answer (score 2):

You could either install a new instance by starting the installer again or simply use the same instance and restore a backup of your prod database to a test database.

Answer (score 1):

> without disturbing other users

This requirement alone means you will have to run your instance on another machine or VM. You cannot expect to maintain an instance on a server without certain things affecting the server as a whole, and any other instance running on it. (e.g. restarts for patching or troubleshooting)

There is no reason if you have the resources to not just put it on another VM, but that all depends on what you want to test (e.g. unit, integration or performance testing).

With regards to duplicating your server, you can utilize [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/commands). The `Start-SqlMigration` would perform the work to bring over the major parts. To make it the easiest process it helps to make sure your new SQL Server instance has the same drive configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Just [create new instance](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/create_multiple_instances), and then restore your prod. database on that instance. You might need to create users there.

Following might help with creating users and mapping them to users in DB.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [myDBUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'myPassword' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[myDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
USE mdb
exec sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Update_One',@UserNamePattern = 'myDBUser', @LoginName = 'myDBUser'
```

Comment: I am talking about 150 DBs so copying each and everyone will take alot of time.

Comment: the DB is 100 GB. how can I backup the WHOLE INSTANCE with everything and Users (LDAP) !!!???

Comment: You are DB admin. You know how to write scripts. BACKUP DATABASE database TO backup_device [ ,...n ] [ WITH with_options [ ,...o ] ] ; And regarding users. They are defined in two places - in DB itself and backup will take care of it and in the instance for which the above command is usefull as it will create mapping between user in DB and user in server. Especially when server user doesn't exist. AFAIK - there is no such thing as BACKUP INSTANCE. But [backup all DB's](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/) can come handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this work using DBATools's [Start-SqlMigration](https://dbatools.io/functions/start-sqlmigration/) powershell commandlet.

However, I would warn against running both the production & the test instances on the same physical hardware, as you will be starving the production instance of resources.

Comment: Link is 404, broken.